# HP Fortify Cross Site Scripting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ssrs-2008, fortify

I am trying to get a PDF from SSRS report using WebClient Classes in MVC .NET. My solution works fine but I end up with a Cross Site scripting issue when I run a scan over my solution. Below is my code in gist.

```
     public void SavePdfReport(string ReportName, string filePath)
    {

            var filebytes = File(SavePdfReport(ReportName), Configurations.FileType);
            FileProcessing.ByteArrayToFile(filePath, filebytes.FileContents);                     
    }


     public static byte[] SavePdfReport(string ReportName)
    {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            return client.DownloadData(ReportName);
    }
```

ReportName is the name of the ssrs report and filepath is the path where I want to store it.
Can someone please help me in fixing this issue.